# Is there a built-in method to replicate a collection to a "follower" collection in the same region?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

CosmosDB can geo-replicate collections and clients can be configured to make (read-only) queries to these "follower" regions.

Is there a built-in way for CosmosDB to provide a "follower" collection in the same region?

The scenario for using that is to use the "main" collection for fast interactive queries, and use the "follower" collection for slower, heavier backend queries, without the possibility of hitting limits and causing throttling that would impact the interactive case.

The usual answer for "copying" collections is to use a change feed (possibly via an Azure function), but this is "manual" work and the client (me) would have to take care of general dev-ops overhead like provisioning, telemetry, monitoring, alerting, key rotation etc.

I'd like to know if there's a "managed" way to do this, like there is for geo-replication.

Comment: Sounds like a use case the analytics storage could  help with https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/updates/new-analytics-storage-for-azure-cosmos-db-is-now-in-preview/

Comment: Just keep in mind: Cosmos DB Analytical storage is in Preview. Also, it is accessed differently (Spark-based, not via the Cosmos DB SQL query engine).

Answer (score 2):

The built-in geo-replication feature only works when replicating to different regions. You cannot replicate the same collection(s) back to the same region.

You'll need to set this up yourself. As you've already mentioned, you can use Change Feed to do this (though you called it a "manual" process and I don't see it as such, since this can be completely automated in code). You can also incorporate a messaging/event pattern: subscribe to database update events, and have multiple consumers writing to different database collections, per your querying needs.

Also: by having an independent collection where you provide the data-movement code, you can choose a different data model for your slower, heavier backend queries (maybe with a different partition key; maybe with some helpful aggregations; etc.).

There's really no way to avoid the added infrastructure setup.

Answer (score 1):

Replication is limited to a single container/collection. For most scenarios like yours, one would use an alternate partition key to make the second collection read optimized. You should also review your top queries and consider using an alternate database which is more read optimize.

You could use this new tool:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-cosmosdb-live-data-migrator